# Will there be an install script to install unity on non-Ubuntu distributions?

Tags: gnome, unity, programming, development

This is less a question to the developers of Unity and Canonical than a question about Ubuntu itself so please excuse me if this question doesn't belong on this site.

While the question seems to speak for itself, maybe the word install script is a little abstract; I'm talking about a script which not only checks for the required dependencies but also patches gnome libraries and such.

As a programmer, I know this is a lot of work and I can't ask the Ubuntu developers to spend their time on other distributions but, in the case that an install script is entirely impossible, there should at least be a document with guidelines on how to install Unity, patch Gnome and what is required to take the necessary steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wider external community likes unity enough, someone might write a script, port it, package it, etc, but that's a bit out of scope for the unity developers to think about really.

However it is up to the developers on whether to support other distributions, and with the work involved, unlikely to happen directly, unless GNOME changes their attitude toward canonical (again unlikely; Red Hat vs Canonical is the main reason for the whole issue, if we are honest).

Answer (score 1):

An install script would have no use for others distribution. Unity itself uses a standard build system, so yes, it should be build on other distro as long as the build depends are met. As for the gnome patches those would need to be incorporated by other distributions in their packaging, this is not something that could be done externally with a script.

Comment: patches don't need to be built in upstream. You just need the source.

Comment: Actually an install script would be most useful for other distributions. It would be very cool to see a jhbuild module (or something like it) that automatically fetched the head of all the related Unity branches as well has the Ubuntu patched version of GTK. Then it would build and install them in a non-default location just for development testing. GNOME-Shell can be built this way: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell#Building